# Map QML TableView row on activated back to QModelIndex

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, tableview, qmodelindex

I have a QML `TableView` where I display some data from a model implementing `QAbstractItemModel`. But instead of using it directly I wrap it in a `QSortFilterProxyModel` for the sorting and filtering features.

Now if I e.g. have a heavily filtered view and activate a row I want to do something with the activated model item. But the `onActivated()` handler only gives me the row number I clicked on but I think I need the `QModelIndex` to query the underlying model for the item. I also can't implement something like `model.get(row)` since the model has now mapping of rows to indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how it is supposed to work. You implement index and data in your custom sortfilterproxymodel like this:

```
@pyqtSlot(int, int, result=QModelIndex)
@pyqtSlot(int, int, QModelIndex, result=QModelIndex)
def index(self, row, column, parent=QModelIndex()):
    return super().index(row, column, parent)

@pyqtSlot(QModelIndex, int, result=QVariant)
def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
    return super().data(index, role)
```

Now you can call e.g. like this in QML

```
property var qt_UserRole: 256 // FIXME: Qt.UserRole is not exported
model.data(model.index(row, 0), qt_UserRole + 1)
```